# Multiple DataGrids with different Resources?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have two `DataGrids` with different styles and Resources but one `DataGrid` Resource overwrites the other `DataGrid` Resource.
So my question is can I set a specific resource to a `DataGrid` with for example a `x:Key`?

My XAML Code:

#### First DataGrid.Resources:

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
   <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Black"/>
   <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}" Color="Black"/>
   <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="White"/>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

#### Second DataGrid.Resources:

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
   <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}" Color="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightColor}"/>
   <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextColor}"/>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope that I am understanding your question correctly, on how you want 2 data grid resources not to conflict with each other. You could try something likes this if they are going to be in the same file...

```
        <DataGrid.Resources>

            <Style x:Key="DataGrid1Style"  TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
            <Setter Property="......" Value="....." />
            ...
            ...
            ...
            </Style>

            <Style x:Key="DataGrid2Style"  TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
            <Setter Property="......" Value="....." />
            ...
            ...
            ...
            </Style>

        </DataGrid.Resources>
```

If they are not in the same file I would suggest that you create a Resource Dictionary file and add the 2 styles in there and just add it to your App.xaml like this assuming you have a Resource folder > Styles folder > and then your DatagridStyles.xaml file:

```
        <Application.Resources>
                <ResourceDictionary>
                    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                        <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/DatagridStyles.xaml"/>
                    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                </ResourceDictionary>
            </Application.Resources>

        </Application>
```

This allows you to have global access to the 2 datagrid styles

You would then assign the styles to your datagrid like this...

```
        <DataGrid Style="{StaticResource DataGrid1Style}">
        </DataGrid>

        <DataGrid Style="{StaticResource DataGrid2Style}">
        </DataGrid>
```

Let me know if this works